# syntax error when running a scripts to get network name and password in terminal

Tags: python

I am trying to run a python code directly from my terminal:

```
>>> if len(profile_names) != 0:
...     for name in profile_names:
...             wifi_profile = dict()
...             profile_info = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name], capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
...             if re.serach("Security Key        : Absent", profile_info):
...                     continue
...             else:
...                     wifi_profile["ssid"] = name
...                     profile_info_pass = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profile", name, "key=clear"], capture_output=True).stdout.decode()
...                     password = re.search("Key Content        : (.*)\r", profile_info_pass)
...                     if password == None:
...                             wifi_profile["password"] = None
...                     else:
...                             wifi_profile["password"] = password[1]
...                     wifi_list.append(wifi_profile)
... for x in range(len(wifi_list)):
  File "<stdin>", line 16
    for x in range(len(wifi_list)):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What is the cause of the error please, i don't seem to get it.

Comment: Writing code of that size directly in the interactive prompt is just _begging_ for indentation errors, like the one you're experiencing. Is there any reason why you can't use a script?

Comment: @Brian I just decided to test the command line out and moreover, i learnt somethings using it. I can then start using scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I had to leave an extra line by pressing the enter button before then starting the **for block**

> When a compound statement is entered interactively, it must be followed by a blank line to indicate completion (since the parser cannot guess when you have typed the last line). Note that each line within a basic block must be indented by the same amount.